# Rigging with rigify

Tags: rigging, interface, mmd-tools

Ok I've been trying to make a custom rig for a stick figure and whenever I try to generate the rig. It says the mmd bone doesn't support the ui data. I'm severely malding over here can someone help?

Comment: to get help and an answer you need to provide more details. How have you created the rig (from scratch? customized template?) Have you deleted bones? Have you set the Rig Types? Maybe share a demo file.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. You must have imported the bones that now serve as a metarig from another application. I can't say exactly which one and that's not that important.

You have to go over each bone in the metarig and take a look at their Custom properties. Some of them will have "mmd" in their name. Remove those Custom Properties. DO NOT remove the real Rigify properties such as "limbs.leg" etc.

You may have to check for Custom Properties in both Edit and Pose mode. Once all of the bad properties are gone, you should be able to generate.